# PHP sum quantity in array loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to sum quantity over elements in my array with the same **car_name and edition_num** but different buyers, and I need to put the total quantity back into the array so I can save it to the database.

The problem im having is the way I choose to sum the total. It works by putting matching elements into a `quantity` array, unless it hits an element that does not match, then it ->

```
1. runs a loop over the size of the quantity array and sums the total
2. empties array 
3. puts the new element into it.
```

The problem is in my inventory loop the `total_sum` I need to save is into the last index of my array, but this is not working:

`$inventory[$k-1]['total_buy'] = $buy_sum;`

What is the correct way to do this?
http://ideone.com/ZjnuRi

```
<?php

$len = '[{"car_name":"Mazda","edition_num":"Prius","code":"M",
"buyer":"JamesT","used":0,"buy_price":3.877,"buy_quantity":4,
"sell_price":4.175,"sell_quantity":0},
{"car_name":"Mazda","edition_num":"Prius","code":"M",
"buyer":"steveF","used":0,"buy_price":3.879,"buy_quantity":1,
"sell_price":4.174,"sell_quantity":3},
{"car_name":"Mazda","edition_num":"Prius","code":"M",
"buyer":"KirkL","used":0,"buy_price":3.879,"buy_quantity":4,
"sell_price":4.174,"sell_quantity":0},
{"car_name":"Toyota","edition_num":"Prius","code":"U",
"buyer":"JamesT","used":0,"buy_price":0.007,"buy_quantity":2,
"sell_price":0.042,"sell_quantity":2},
{"car_name":"Toyota","edition_num":"Prius","code":"U",
"buyer":"steveF","used":0,"buy_price":0.007,
"buy_quantity":0,"sell_price":0.042,"sell_quantity":4},{"car_name":"Toyota","edition_num":"Prius","code":"U",
"buyer":"KirkL","used":0,"buy_price":0.007,"buy_quantity":-2,
"sell_price":0.042,"sell_quantity":6}]';


$inventory = json_decode($len,true);

$timeNow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$q_c = array();

        for($k=0 ; $k < sizeof($inventory); $k++)
        {
        $buy_sum = 0;
        $sell_sum = 0;


        if(empty($q_c))
        {
        $q_c[] = 
        array('car_name'=>$inventory[$k]['car_name'], 
        'edition_num' => $inventory[$k]['edition_num'] , 
        'buy_quantity' => $inventory[$k]['buy_quantity'] , 
        'sell_quantity' => $inventory[$k]['sell_quantity'] ,
        'buyer' => $inventory[$k]['buyer']);
         }
        // set quantity control to the current car if not empty: 

         //if quantity control not empty put current car into it.

        //same car: 
        else
        {

        if($inventory[$k]['car_name'] == $q_c[0]['car_name'] && $inventory[$k]['edition_num'] == $q_c[0]['edition_num'])
        {

        $q_c[] = 
        array('car_name'=>$inventory[$k]['car_name'], 
        'edition_num' => $inventory[$k]['edition_num'] , 
        'buy_quantity' => $inventory[$k]['buy_quantity'] , 
        'sell_quantity' => $inventory[$k]['sell_quantity'] ,
        'buyer' => $inventory[$k]['buyer']
        );

        }

        //new : sum total for last car:
        else
        {
        for($i=0; $i < sizeof($q_c); $i++)
        {

        $buy_qty = $q_c[$i]['buy_quantity'];
        $sell_qty = $q_c[$i]['sell_quantity'];

        $buy_sum += intval ($buy_qty); 
        $sell_sum += intval ($sell_qty); 

        //----THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK ---
            $inventory[$k-1]['total_buy'] = $buy_sum;
            //----THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK ---

        }
        //clear out the array
        $q_c = array();

        //push current car into it: 
        $q_c[] = 
        array('car_name'=>$inventory[$k]['car_name'], 
        'edition_num' => $inventory[$k]['edition_num'] , 
        'buy_quantity' => $inventory[$k]['buy_quantity'] , 
        'sell_quantity' => $inventory[$k]['sell_quantity'] ,
        'buyer' => $inventory[$k]['buyer']
        );          

        }

        }

         echo '<pre>';
         print_r($inventory[$k]);
        echo '</pre>';

        }




?>
```

### Expectd output: The last array holds total_buy which is the sum of all buy_quantites & total_sell which is a sum of all sell_quantities including itself

```
Array
(
    [car_name] => Mazda
    [edition_num] => Prius
    [code] => M
    [buyer] => JamesT
    [used] => 0
    [buy_price] => 3.877
    [buy_quantity] => 4
    [sell_price] => 4.175
    [sell_quantity] => 0
)
Array
(
    [car_name] => Mazda
    [edition_num] => Prius
    [code] => M
    [buyer] => steveF
    [used] => 0
    [buy_price] => 3.879
    [buy_quantity] => 1
    [sell_price] => 4.174
    [sell_quantity] => 3
)
Array
(
    [car_name] => Mazda
    [edition_num] => Prius
    [code] => M
    [buyer] => KirkL
    [used] => 0
    [buy_price] => 3.879
    [buy_quantity] => 4
    [sell_price] => 4.174
    [sell_quantity] => 0
    [total_buy] => 9
    [total_sell] => 3
)
```

Comment: Could you provide a model of the expected output?

Comment: @ryanVicent this isnt one of those questions.

Answer (score -1):

You're making things so complicated by creating all those extra loops, variables, arrays etc. Haven't tested but this should work;

```
$inventory = json_decode($len,true);

$buys = $sells = array();
$cars = array();

foreach($inventory as $index => $item){

    $car = $item['car_name'] . $item['edition_num'];
    $buys[$car] += $item['buy_quantity'];
    $sells[$car] += $item['sell_quantity'];
    $numberofCars[$car]++;

    $cars[$car][] = $item;
}

foreach($cars as $car_group){
    foreach($car_group as $index => $car){

        if($index == count($car_group)-1){
            $car['total_buy'] = $buys[ $car['car_name'] . $car['edition_num'] ];
            $car['total_sell'] = $sells[ $car['car_name'] . $car['edition_num'] ];
        }

        print_r($car);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect as it does not take into account the part where I need to only sum things with matching `car_name` and `edition_num`. The code is there for a reason.

Comment: Edited the code. Still way better than yours. And as a thanks for that minus one, didn't bother with "same seller" rule, so good luck with the rest.